# Timer on how long it take to load a resources (C# Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, real-time

I would like to `Debug.Log` my loading method on how long it takes before they can fully load all my resources. Here's how I loaded them from my resources.

```
yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/minimap_type_b (x_ 1575, 1356)", tf));
yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/replay", tf));

tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 1~2)");
yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/logo", tf));
yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/card_open_window", tf));
yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/ranking", tf));
yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/top_bar", tf));

tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 10~11)");
yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/midterm_loading", tf));

tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 12)");
yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/game_result", tf));

loading.SetValue(0.02f);    // 2%.
```

My problem here is that I do not know what to use. `Time.timeSinceLevelLoad` or `Time.realtimeSinceStartup`. Plus I don't really know how to use them. Could someone guide me?

Comment: I believe the most accurate way to calculate the execution time is to use a Stopwatch, more information you can find here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've been reading some forums but they're always referring to those two function.

Comment: Depends on what kind of timespans we are talking about. Seconds/Milliseconds/Nanoseconds? Depending on how easy you want to add this and how precise you need the result you could use StopWatch, DateTime or HighPerformanceCounters.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer i just want a simple one sir that calculates on how long are my app taking to load the resources.

Comment: @NoobProgrammer Easiest way would be to remeber the Timestamp before and after the loading, e.g: `DateTime start = DateTime.Now; Your code here; DateTime end = DateTime.Now; TimeSpan elapsedTime = end - start; double elapsedSeconds = elapsedTime.TotalSeconds;`.

Comment: So it's something like this `DateTime start = DateTime.Now; loading.setValue(0.02); DateTime end = DateTime.Now; TimeSpanelapsedTime = end - start; double elapsedSeconds = elapsedTime.TotalSeconds;` ??? like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the idea of this . While i was waiting for the answers a bulb pops out .

```
 public float start_time;
 Debug.Log(string.Format("End LoadUI - {0}s", Time.realtimeSinceStartup - start_time));
```

Thanks guys.